# Limit Pagination Numbers

Tags: javascript, pagination

I've got a pagination up and running which works fine. However I would like it to only display 5 page numbers at for example 1.2.3.4.5 then when I click next it goes 6.7.8.9.10 and so on.

I've created it using JavaScript and the code is below.

I have tried multiple pieces of code from various places but i'm positive i'm missing something as nothing seems to work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  

    pageSize = 2;
    pagesCount = $(".content").length;
    var currentPage = 1;

    /////////// PREPARE NAV ///////////////
    var nav = '';
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize);
    for (var s=0; s<totalPages; s++){
        nav += '<li class="numeros"><a href="#">'+(s+1)+'</a></li>';
    }
    $(".pag_prev").after(nav);
    $(".numeros").first().addClass("active");
    //////////////////////////////////////

    showPage = function() {
        $(".content").hide().each(function(n) {
            if (n >= pageSize * (currentPage - 1) && n < pageSize * currentPage)
                $(this).show();
        });
    }
    showPage();


    $(".pagination li.numeros").click(function() {
        $(".pagination li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        currentPage = parseInt($(this).text());
        showPage();
    });

    $(".pagination li.pag_prev").click(function() {
        if($(this).next().is('.active')) return;
        $('.numeros.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        currentPage = currentPage > 1 ? (currentPage-1) : 1;
        showPage();
    });

    $(".pagination li.pag_next").click(function() {
        if($(this).prev().is('.active')) return;
        $('.numeros.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        currentPage = currentPage < totalPages ? (currentPage+1) : totalPages;
        showPage();
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide us some more information on what exactly does not work with your code and what exactly you wanted to achieve with it so we can provide you some help. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Currently at the moment every time I add new content the pagination adds another number. So at the minute I currently have numbers 1-10 listed along the bottom of the page. However I would like it so it only displays around 5 numbers until I get to the last one then it changes to another 5 numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question is easy

> However I would like it to only display 5 page numbers

```js
for (var s=0; s<Math.min(totalPages,5); s++) {
  nav += '<li class="numeros"><a href="#">'+ (s + 1) + '</a></li>';
}
```

This limits the number of page numbers displayed to `totalPages` or `5` whichever is smaller.
For the second part of your question - seeing as you [found a lugin which does exactly what you want](https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/) there's not much point trying to replicate the behaviour. You're better off just using it directly. The appropriate code would be along the lines of:

```js
pageSize = 2;
pagesCount = $(".content").length;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize)

$('.pagination').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: totalPages,
  visiblePages: 5,
  onPageClick: function(event, page) {
    var startIndex = (pageSize * (page - 1))
    var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize
    $('.content').hide().filter(function() {
      var idx = $(this).index();
      return idx >= startIndex && idx < endIndex;
    }).show()
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.4.1/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>

<div class="contents text-center">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 1</h1>
    <h3>Page 1 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 2</h1>
    <h3>Page 2 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 3</h1>
    <h3>Page 3 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 4</h1>
    <h3>Page 4 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 5</h1>
    <h3>Page 5 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 6</h1>
    <h3>Page 6 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 7</h1>
    <h3>Page 7 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 8</h1>
    <h3>Page 8 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 9</h1>
    <h3>Page 9 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 10</h1>
    <h3>Page 10 contents...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>NEWS 11</h1>
    <h3>Page 11 contents...</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I have made a quick JSFiddle so its better to show you. I put your code into the script but it wont go past 5 pages even tho there is more content after it.

https://jsfiddle.net/vhyxbr3r/84/

Comment: @oOJimmyP You realise that in your jsfiddle *every* page after 5 says Page 5? ie. it works fine - your markup is wrong

Comment: Yeah i just copied and pasted that part of the code to add more content so it would make more pages/numbers in the pagination

Comment: Ok fine, but you also never included my code from this answer to limit the pagination to 5 pages.

Comment: Sorry i pasted the wrong link ive only just noticed. Here is the JSFiddle with the line of code included that you had given me sorry 

The piece of code that you wrote which works fine in only showing the first 5 numbers but if i try to click past number 5 to what should be number 6 it does nothing.

https://jsfiddle.net/vhyxbr3r/86/

Comment: So at the moment it displays numbers 1-5 so if i get to number 5 and click next i would it to then displays numbers 6-10 for the rest of the hidden content/pages and to keep it going like that every time i add new content to the page. Sorry if it got confusing, i appreciate the help bud

Comment: So you dont want the next/prev button to navigate pages any more, you want it to navigate banks of 5 page numbers (If true, that is weird and will entirely confuse/annoy your users)

Comment: Yeah so something similar to how this works https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/

Comment: You see the devil is in the detail - that example does NOT do what you describe, it does something more complex (both navigating pages and moving the page bank back/forward). Why not just use that plugin if you found one that does what you want?

Comment: Tried the plugin multiple times mate and i just cant get the thing to work. Im new to this type of coding so no idea where im going wrong. However if theres no way of getting it to work with the code ive used then i will just have to put up with it :) thanks for helping tho mate much appreciated

Comment: @oOJimmyP I got that plugin working no problem. I'll update answer now.

Comment: Well i tried the code above exactly how you had it and im doing something wrong somewhere as it just wont work and ive reached the end of my tether lol thanks for all the help anyways mate

Comment: @oOJimmyP The answer *literally* has a working example in it!

Comment: Haha i know mate which is 100% what i cant get my head around as when i try to put it in my webpage it just does nothing which is why im pulling my hair out lol

Comment: Sorry mate was actually being a moron ive now got it working haha Cheers for all the help mate youve done wonders. Very much appreciated!